# Receiving "variable myFunction is undeclared" in Google Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, npm, google-closure-compiler

Attempting to compile two JavaScript files where a function used by both files is declared in only one of those files gives an `undeclared` error.

I tried declaring it in my externs file by entering
`var myFunction = function() {};`

However if I compile doing that I receive: `Variable myFunction declared more than once. First occurrence: [path]`

How do I let Google Closure Compiler know that a function has already been declared if not in the externs file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you appear to be compiling the files separately, your extern method was correct. But the extern is only needed to compile the file that does not define the function.

Since the other file does define the function, it does not need the extern.

Comment: Correct, I am compiling them one by one, however during compilation I always include the externs file since certain files depend on it. I think you are saying I should not include the externs file when compiling that other JavaScript file, and that would work but I would have to modify my code to not include it when it is compiling that particular file. Is that how I should be doing it?